# inner join de 4 tablas con sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs, sequelize.js

tengo una duda quiero sacar esta consulta en codigo sequelize, nodejs
`select products.name, licenses.dateStart, licenses.dateEnd, licenses.asignateDevices,` `licenses.availableDevices, licenses.numDevices from licenses inner join licenses_has_devices on` `licenses.idLicense = licenses_has_devices.licenseIdLicense inner join devices on devices.idDevice =` `licenses_has_devices.deviceIdDevice inner join products on products.idProduct = licenses.productIdProduct;`

tengo que pasarla a sequelize tengo algo así

```
 const licenseDevices = await license.findAll({
            include: {
                model: devices,
                as: 'deviceIdDevice',
            }
        })
```

pero aqui es donde no se como convinar mas tablas.

Answer (score 1):

siempre puedes utilizar la consulta directa utilizando el método query() de la siguiente forma:

```
const licenseDevices = await sequelize.query(
  "select products.name, licenses.dateStart, licenses.dateEnd, licenses.asignateDevices, licenses.availableDevices, licenses.numDevices from licenses inner join licenses_has_devices on licenses.idLicense = licenses_has_devices.licenseIdLicense inner join devices on devices.idDevice = licenses_has_devices.deviceIdDevice inner join products on products.idProduct = licenses.productIdProduct"
  {
  type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT 
  }
);
```

Esto debería devolverte la consulta, si no pones el type:, la consulta también funcionaría, pero te devolvería dos arrays en lugar de uno, el primero con el resultado y el segundo con los metadatos de la consulta, que según el motor de base de datos que estés utilizando no tendría importancia.
Sería algo así:

```
const [licenseDevices, metadata] = await sequelize.query("aquí va la consulta");
```

Answer (score 0):

const licenseDevices = await license.findAll({
include: {
model: devices,
as: 'deviceIdDevice',
include: {
attributes: [‘id’, …..],
model: licenses_has_devices,
where: {
…….
},
include: {
attributes: [‘id’, …..],
model: products,
where: {
…….
},
}
}
}
});

Comment: La respuesta es solo código. Explica cómo ayuda a resolver el problema y dale formato.